# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jena, semantic-web

I'm having trouble with my semantic web application coding. The error says java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec. I'm using Eclipse JEE Luna, Apache Tomcat 7, JDK 7u79, and Apache Jena 3.6.0. The class should be included in Jena jar files right? But why can't the class be found? Thank you so much for your help :)

Coding excerpt:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Model modeltmp = null;
        OntModel mpidb = null;

        System.out.println("DONE1");

        OntModelSpec spec = new OntModelSpec(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);

        mpidb = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(spec,modeltmp);

        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open("C:/Users/USER/workspace/FYP/Ontologies/MangrovePlantImageDatabase.owl");

        mpidb.read(in,"http://www.mangroveplantimagedatabase.com/ontologies/mangroveplantimagedatabase.owl");

        System.out.println("DONE3");
    }
```

Comment: See the javadoc for `ClassNotFoundException`. It is different from the more common `NoClassDefFoundError`. It is not the code that is the problem, it is the runtime environment.

Comment: oh i see, i will give it a try. thank you for your help :)

Comment: I'm getting this error now : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModelSpec It's an error during runtime and not compile time right? How do i resolve this?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError means the runtime classpath does not have the jar for the class while it was present at compile time.

Comment: so i need to change the runtime classpath to be the same as the compile classpath?